# Reactjs onPointer event not functioning properly on mobile browsers

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a finger-painting canvas, which should work on mobile browsers.

My canvas is working properly on pc browsers (by mouse), but not on mobile browsers. The strokes just disappear even if my finger did not leave the screen.

Is it because the swipe gestures in Chrome (which I am using) overwrite the onPointerMove event on some time point?

You can try my canvas [here](http://35.186.165.2:3000/) (my server is not always on). The whole project contains too much code unrelated to this issue so I am not posting those code here.

And my code for Canvas.js is like this:

```
// canvas.js
// modified from https://pusher.com/tutorials/live-paint-react

import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Canvas extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onPointerDown = this.onPointerDown.bind(this);
    this.onPointerMove = this.onPointerMove.bind(this);
    this.endPaintEvent = this.endPaintEvent.bind(this);
  }

  isPainting = false;
  userStrokeStyle = '#EE92C2';
  line = [];
  prevPos = { offsetX: 0, offsetY: 0 };

  onPointerDown({ nativeEvent }) {
    const { offsetX, offsetY } = nativeEvent;
    this.isPainting = true;
    this.prevPos = { offsetX, offsetY };
  }

  onPointerMove({ nativeEvent }) {
    if (this.isPainting) {
      const { offsetX, offsetY } = nativeEvent;
      const offSetData = { offsetX, offsetY };
      // Set the start and stop position of the paint event.
      const positionData = {
        start: { ...this.prevPos },
        stop: { ...offSetData },
      };
      // Add the position to the line array
      this.line = this.line.concat(positionData);
      this.paint(this.prevPos, offSetData, this.userStrokeStyle);
    }
  }
  endPaintEvent() {
    if (this.isPainting) {
      this.isPainting = false;
      //this.sendPaintData();
    }
  }
  paint(prevPos, currPos, strokeStyle) {
    const { offsetX, offsetY } = currPos;
    const { offsetX: x, offsetY: y } = prevPos;

    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
    // Move the the prevPosition of the mouse
    this.ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    // Draw a line to the current position of the mouse
    this.ctx.lineTo(offsetX, offsetY);
    // Visualize the line using the strokeStyle
    this.ctx.stroke();
    this.prevPos = { offsetX, offsetY };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Here we set up the properties of the canvas element. 
    this.canvas.width = 1000;
    this.canvas.height = 800;
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    this.ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    this.ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <canvas
      // We use the ref attribute to get direct access to the canvas element. 
        ref={(ref) => (this.canvas = ref)}
        style={{ background: 'black' }}
        onPointerDown={this.onPointerDown}
        onPointerUp={this.endPaintEvent}
        onPointerMove={this.onPointerMove}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default Canvas;
```

I tried to disable the scrolling and zooming by these code:

index.css

```
html, body {
        overflow-x:hidden;
        overflow-y:hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
}
```

index.html

```
  <script>
        document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
                if (e.target == canvas) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                }
        }, false);
        document.body.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) {
        if (e.target == canvas) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                }
        }, false);
        document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) {
                if (e.target == canvas) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                }
        }, false);
  </script>
```

And I change onPointer events to onTouch events (simply change onPointer to onTouch

e.g. onPointerDown -> onTouchStart

But nothing happened when I draw on the canvas, I am not sure whether I am implementing onTouch events correctly.

Comment: Upon testing it via mobile, I notice that it stops responding to touch events when the page is scrolling. I did some searching and found this potential fix for that issue. http://bencentra.com/code/2014/12/05/html5-canvas-touch-events.html#touch-input

Comment: You might want to set the size of the canvas to 100% of the mobile width/height, and prevent scrolling entirely.

Comment: @KenoClayton I disabled both scrolling and zooming, and the problem remains. BTW, when I had disabled scrolling but NOT zooming, if I double-clicked on the canvas, it was zooming and drawing (without this problem) simultaneously. I have updated by testing site.

Comment: Are you using the specified touch events? `touchstart` `touchend` `touchmove`?

Comment: I was still using onPointer events, because I still wanted that to work on the desktop. I will try whether it works fine by touch events.

Comment: I tried onTouch events, and I cannot draw on the canvas totally. I am not sure whether I am implementing onTouch events correctly. I just replace onPointer event names with onTouch event names.

Comment: You can use both events, just ensure that you have touch events defined as well. The article should detail how they did it. Also the MDN reference is very helpful on it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events